# How to deploy a package in another operating system

Tags: deployment, rpm, static-linking

I have a project written in C++ 14 (compiled in my machine with GCC 6.2) and my machine run on Fedora 26. Now I need to deploy into customer's server that run RedHat 6, and GCC 4.8. I can not change or install new things in this server (except my package). But this server doesn't contain 2 package that required to my project is `numactl` and `hwloc`. 
If I build these library as static library and import into my project (in Fedora 26), then package these library with my project into a RPM package, will it run on the server.

Is it the best way? I never do this work before.

I'm sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your package for RedHat 6. Create source rpm (src.rpm) and run:

```
mock -r epel-6-x86_64  your-package.src.rpm
```

This way you will get package which can be installed on RHEL6.